# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core.forms'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make checkout form for my website. 
I receive an error saying No module named 'core.forms'.

Here are my files:

View.py

```py
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, View
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import CheckoutForm
from .models import Item, OrderItem, Order

class CheckoutView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm()
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(self.request, "checkout.html", context)

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CheckoutForm(self.request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            print("The form is valid")
            return redirect('core:checkout')
```

Form.py

```py
from django import forms
from django_countries.fields import CountryField


class CheckoutForm(forms.Form):
    street_address = forms.CharField()
    apartment_address = forms.CharField(required=False)
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)')
    zip = forms.CharField()
    same_billing_address = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    save_info = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckboxInput())
    payment_option = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

error msg when run `python manage.py runserver`

```py
File "C:\Users\Dell\project5\core\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .views import (
  File "C:\Users\Dell\project5\core\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .forms import CheckoutForm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core.forms'
```

I am new to Django

Plz, Help

Comment: Either you got a typo in your question or the problem is that your file is called `Form.py` and you import `.forms`. Could you provide the relevant project structure?

Comment: And if you could provide the whole error message, it's very useful to trace the root cause

Comment: thank sir, i will add error msg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the problem is that you are importing `from .forms` but your file is called `Form.py`.

Because your file is named that way you can't import from there.

If you change the filename from `Form.py` to `forms.py` it should work.